# Rotate elements in a String which has more than two characters and print them out

Tags: java

I am trying to rotate the elements in a String which have more than two elements and print them out.

```
public class Solution1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String strArray[] = { "ab", "bc", "abc", "ca", "cba", "xyz", "xy" };
        int shift = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < strArray.length; j++,i++) {
                if (strArray[j].length() >= 3) {
                    strArray[shift] = strArray[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
            shift++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
            System.out.println(strArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting correct output for: `{ "ab", "bc", "abc", "ca", "cba", "xyz", "xyz" }`

but not: `{ "ab", "bc", "abc", "ca", "cba", "xyz", "xy" }`

What is wrong?

Comment: resolved !!!   instead of out side the shift increment ..modified strArray[shift++] = strArray[j];

Comment: Better explanation and corrections

Comment: Voting for removing this one. Useless question, typogrphical error, possible duplicate. Adds nothing to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code will work if you put `shift++;` in place of `break;` statement. However, your solution can be simplified and improved.

Comment: instead of out side the shift increment ..modified strArray[shift++] = strArray[j]; this reolved the issue.